# What is the best way to load a large Excel sheet to an Informix table?

Tags: excel, informix

I want to insert data into an **Informix** table from an Excel sheet. This Excel sheet contains nearly `300000` records. What is the best way to load this data? Can I use **IBM** `ipload` software to do this work?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `ipload`, but I used `LOAD/UNLOAD` and UNL format because it is quite easy:

1. export Excel file to CSV text
2. convert it into UNL file readable for Informix dbaccess utility, see: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_144.htm
3. import it using dbaccess `LOAD` command

If you are not familiar with UNL file format then fill your table with some records and export it using `UNLOAD` statement.